# lz4 data compression with MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have a site where we store mostly text. Recently, I have seen huge increase in database size and I was worried, so I started to work on this problem.
After doing some research I came up with a solution that will compress text with lz4 compression algorithm and then store it to the database.

```
https://github.com/kjdev/php-ext-lz4
```

Now the problem is: when I save it to the database, it is not saved correctly. For example,"?" signs get added, like here:

```
?Home - PER&#039;AN and POOR
```

I have set the table encoding to

> utf8mb4_general_ci

So does anyone have an idea how to fix it, or any other suggestion to reduce the database size?

database column type :: text

Comment: Character set on the database field in question? And what was the original value of the field?

Comment: You don't include any details such as how you're saving it to the database, or what the column type in the database is. You can't save binary data to a text column.

Comment: before data insert its set to utf8mb4_general_ci   , because utf8 permits only the Unicode characters that can be represented with 3 bytes in UTF-8.

Comment: miken32 database coloumn type is text and am just inserting it as come from lzcompress function

Comment: just switched from mysql to mariadb which have page compression feature :: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/compression/             any idea how can i compressed or switch my existing db of 100mb